# Parsing a list with double backslashes in Python3 and converting to a dict object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a peculiar list in Python as:

```
peculiar_list=['"{\\n  \\"persons\\": \\"person 1\\",\\n  \\"score\\": \\"Very Good\\",\\n  \\"comment\\": \\"This result was found to be very good for the the user\'s interest.\\",\\n  \\"level\\": \\"high level\\"\\n}"',
 '"{\\n  \\"persons\\": \\"person 2\\",\\n  \\"score\\": \\"Pretty Good\\",\\n  \\"comment\\": \\"This result, coupled with other data, was found to be pretty good.\\",\\n  \\"level\\": \\"high level\\"\\n}"']
```

I would like to get rid of the `\\n`, `\\` and ultimately return a clean `dict` object to allow

```
peculiar_list[0]['persons']
```

to show "person 1". Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: The list doesn't have double backslashes. It has single backslashes, which are shown doubled to indicate that they're literal, not part of an escape sequence.

Comment: My advice when seeing “peculiar” data like that is to track down the thing/person that screwed it up and fix/educate them.  If you try to adapt to broken output instead of fixing it, they’ll only find more creative ways to break it and you may end up in an arms race that you can’t win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list contains JSON that has been encoded twice, so call `json.loads()` twice to decode it.

```
json.loads(json.loads(peculiar_list[0]))['persons']
```

Comment: Thank you, how did you know it was encoded twice?

Comment: Because newlines are first encoded as `\n`, and then that gets encoded as `\\n`.